# SQL Server create checksum out of multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, hash, checksum

I have a table with product delivery information. I get daily files, which append to this table. But, if something goes wrong with the import,I can't simply reimport the same file, as it already might have imported some of the data and then I would have duplicates.

I am thinking about adding a checksum/hash row so I can compare the lines and omit already existing stuff.

The table looks like this (simplified):

- id (identity row, integer)
- ordernr (integer)
- item (varchar)
- itemcount (integer)
- deliverydate (date)
- ... some more stuff

I would like to add a row 'checksum', which would be a combined hash of the rows ordernr, item, itemcount and deliverydate. As the table is fairly large (1m+ rows),I would even prefer a right(hash,8), so a varchar(8) would be enough for the checksum row.

So far I got here:

```
SELECT o1.rdid, HASHBYTES('md5', (
    SELECT ordernr, item, deliverydate, itemcount
    FROM shop_tt_deliveries_uk o2
    WHERE o2.rdid = o1.rdid FOR XML RAW))
FROM shop_tt_deliveries_uk o1
```

that generates hashes likes this:

```
rdid    (No column name)
98851   0xA819EEB0B7463DCB11AE8170879F867C
98852   0x73DB5FE112707BB3D9564DE063882F30
98853   0x3F81DBCED4D6B200CD605BC774FD5EB4
98854   0xF388A700995F8B589AE31CFE0AEF9568
```

but already adding the right() result in strange stuff (where i was expecting '879F867C' for the first line):

```
rdid    (No column name)
98851   ®p‡Ÿ†|
98852   ÙVMàcˆ/0
98853   Í`[Çtý^´
98854   šãþ
```

and updating the table does not work at all:

```
UPDATE shop_tt_deliveries_uk d
SET checksum = HASHBYTES('md5', (
    SELECT ordernr, item, deliverydate, itemcount
    FROM shop_tt_deliveries_uk o2
    WHERE o2.rdid = o1.rdid ))
WHERE checksum IS NULL
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

```
 declare @source varbinary(max), @id int
 declare chk cursor for SELECT o1.rdid, HASHBYTES('md5', (SELECT ordernr, item, deliverydate, itemcount FROM shop_tt_deliveries_uk o2 WHERE o2.rdid = o1.rdid FOR XML RAW)) FROM shop_tt_deliveries_uk o1
open chk
fetch next from chk into @id, @source
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
  select @source = right(cast('' as xml).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@source"))', 'varchar(max)'),8)
  update shop_tt_deliveries_uk d SET checksum = @source WHERE checksum IS NULL //put your more conditions
  fetch next from chk into @id, @source
end
```

Comment: wow, that was fast.  i only got one error running this: Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 7
Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
i'm running sql server 2012

Comment: ok, changed varbinary to varchar in the first line.  it's running now.  waiting to see what happens...  might take a while it seems to process all existing lines.

Comment: hmmm, doing an endless loop (i added some condition to limit the count) with:
(414 row(s) affected)
(414 row(s) affected)
(414 row(s) affected)
but nothing gets updated in the database...